# How to use boost io_service as a class variable

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

All the examples that I have seen are using `boost::asio` in the main function like this:

```cpp
int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    server server1(io_service, 1980);   
    boost::thread t(boost::bind(&io_service::run, &io_service));
    
    return 0;
}
```

How can I use them as class variables?

```cpp
class TcpConnect
{
private:
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    server server1;
    boost::thread t;

    void initBoost() // I want to create a boost thread in this function
}
```

This is the server file definition:

```cpp
class session
{
public:
    session(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
        : socket_(io_service)
    {
    }
    
    tcp::socket& socket()
    {
        return socket_;
    }
    
    void start()
    {
        socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
            boost::bind(&session::handle_read, this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }
    
    void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& error,
        size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
                boost::asio::buffer(data_, bytes_transferred),
                boost::bind(&session::handle_write, this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        }
        else
        {
            delete this;
        }
    }
    
    void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& error)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
                boost::bind(&session::handle_read, this,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
        }
        else
        {
            delete this;
        }
    }
    
private:
    tcp::socket socket_;
    enum { max_length = 1024 };
    char data_[max_length];
};
    
class server
{
public:
    server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, short port)
        : io_service_(io_service),
        acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port))
    {
        session* new_session = new session(io_service_);
        acceptor_.async_accept(new_session->socket(),
            boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this, new_session,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
    
    void handle_accept(session* new_session,
        const boost::system::error_code& error)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            new_session->start();
            new_session = new session(io_service_);
            acceptor_.async_accept(new_session->socket(),
                boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this, new_session,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        }
        else
        {
            delete new_session;
        }
    }
    
private:
    boost::asio::io_service& io_service_;
    tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
};
```

Comment: I'm not too sure what your question is. It seems to be laid out fairly well, but then... Huge code block that I can't relate to the stuff at the beginning.

Comment: You should use `boost::asio::io_service &io_service` variable declaration not the `boost::asio::io_service io_service`, becuase in the latter case you are obligated to make a copy (or move the instance of io_service) to initialize the variable which is impossible AFAIK.

Comment: @user4581301 the code that i am showing in the begning is how i am currently using the boost asio in the main function.

Comment: how can i declare these varibles in the class and than use them.

Comment: @user4581301 i have updated my code , please have a look.

Comment: Your question is not related to asio but to "C++ variable scope". Google it !